# How do I adjust screen brightness / backight on a Toshiba Satellite C50D?

Tags: 12.04, laptop, brightness, backlight

I know this is a known bug, it been asked and answered thousands of times before. I've spent the past couple of months searching for a solution and all have failed.

My Fn keys won't adjust brightness and if I go to system **setting > Brightness**  and Lock the brightness bar seems to appear for a split second then disappears.

> echo 5 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness

changes the value of the brightness but the brightness does not actually change.

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 lts on a toshiba satellite C50D

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full solution but installing [indicator-brightness](http://codevanrohde.nl/wordpress/?p=128) is a nice workaround that worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04, but I suspect it should work on 12.04 as well.

[image]

Here is [another page about it](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/brightness-control-ubuntu). All that's needed is to type these commands in a terminal window:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:indicator-brightness/ppa

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install indicator-brightness
```

After rebooting it should then appear as shown in the picture above. Otherwise search and launch the application manually.